# How to create accordion table with query of list in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013

my problem is “ how to get query from SharePoint list and show in the accordion table with more items.. by javascript?

I have a 2 list of sharepoint that should use one of them for column’s header and after that i need query from another list with filter of this column and show in the accordion table..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.